# Nginx upstream servers for inside/outside docker-compose

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'd like to have a Nginx proxying a service that could be running inside docker-compose or outside as a simple process.

```
http {

    upstream web {
        server web:80; # when running in Docker-Compose
        server 127.0.0.1:80; # when running outside
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location /web/ {
            proxy_pass http://web;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

But when trying to run it outside of docker-compose, I get an error that the host `web` can't be resolved. I know it is a restriction for nginx to be able to resolve the upstream servers and the moment of starting, but is there another way of achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using the `Dockerhost` docker image and replacing the values of the `proxy_pass` as part of the nginx docker startup command.